# How to create Prisma model with related item

Tags: prisma

Here I have two models, a venue and an address. Would it be better practise to have the venue address within the venue model or is it best to keep them separate?

The second question would be how do I create a venue with a linked address? Having read the Prisma documentation I can not seem to find the answer I am looking for. I am getting errors from the pine that includes `propertyNumber` like so

> Type '{ title: string; images: string[]; address: { propertyNumber:
> string; }; }' is not assignable to type
> '(Without<VenueCreateWithoutUserInput,
> VenueUncheckedCreateWithoutUserInput>

```js
await prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Samss',
    email: 'sasm@gmail.com',
    Venue: {
      create: { 
        title: 'new venue',
        images: ['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/01/31/05/59/zebra-7757193_960_720.jpg'],
        address: {
          propertyNumber: "12"
        },
        
      }
    },
  },
})
```

```
model Venue {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  title     String   @db.VarChar(255)
  address   Address? @relation(fields: [addressId], references: [id])
  published Boolean  @default(false)
  userId    String
  images    String[]
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  addressId String?
}

model Address {
  id             String  @id @default(cuid())
  propertyNumber String
  firstLine      String
  Area           String
  Country        String
  zipCode        String
  lat            Decimal
  lng            Decimal
  Venue          Venue[]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that it will depend on how often you will need the venues without the address? If it's never, just put the address fields inside the venue.

Remember, that each model will result in a single table, and accessing each venue with its address will join both tables, resulting in poor performance over time.

Regarding your error, it might come from your 1-N relation between `Venue` and `Addres`. You should have a 1-1.

Just put the address in your Venue, and you'll be fine.